# Is it possible to duplicate eyes?

Tags: naruto

#### This question contains spoilers for anime viewers and early manga viewers.

> When Nagato was revived with Edo Tensei, he had Madara's eyes. When Madara was revived, he had his original eyes too (Rinnegan, much like Nagato).

Is this exploitable? Can I repeat this cycle of transplant and revive to duplicate strong eyes? How does that work really?

Comment: I think the same day KISHI wrote that he went to sleep too much late.

Comment: Even if this duplication worked, obviously only *ONE* of the pairs of eyes would be in a "living" person - the rest would be copies in zombie bodies.  In other words you could duplicate zombie eyes but not living ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although never explicitly stated (till now), it seems Kabuto's upgraded Edo Tensei allows him to revive a shinobi with a mix of attributes from different portions of their lifetime. Shortly after showing the last coffin to Tobi, Kabuto exclaims that he had surpassed the Second Hokage and Orochimaru. It is very likely this is what he was referring to.

It is possible to have multiple copies, and this has already been exploited with Itachi's Sharingan and Madara's Rinnegan.

Both Itachi and Sasuke had Itachi's Sharingan at the same time. The revived Nagato **and Tobi** both have Madara's Rinnegan. If Itachi had not sealed Nagato, there would indeed be *three* copies of Madara's Rinnegan active at the same time.

The Madara's Rinnegan case shows how it could be exploited multiple times. If Obito dies and is revived, while his Rinnegan is transplanted to someone else, you could then have *four* Rinnegan, which are all really Madara's Rinnegan.

Comment: Though your answer may have been before this was revealed, but when Madara was revived, he lost his Rinnegan and went blind. I recall someone also said Edo Tensei Rinnegan were fake Rinnegan which could not summon the Gedo Mazo. Also, its likely that, like all other damage done to Edo Tensei bodies, the eyes would crumble to paper like scraps and then try to remerge with the body, or remain useless and new eyes would form.

Comment: Madara lost his eyes when he was revived with the Rinne Tensei, he had his Rinnegan when he was revived by Edo Tensei. Those are two different jutsus. The Edo Tensei Rinnegan could not be used to cast the Rinne Tensei, that is why Madara needed to use the real Rinnegan (which was with Tobi at the time).

Comment: That said though, Kishimito-sama seemed to have hurried through the final battle at times, and was not always consistent. For instance, Madara somehow summoned Susannoo *without eyes* at one point even though it was explicitly stated earlier that it required Mangekyou Sharingan in both eyes.

Comment: It was originally stated by itachi that when you master the Amaterasu and Tsukuyomi, you get Susanoo, but Sasuke, Madara, and Kakashi do not have both of those techniques, but got Susanoo. It was kind of changed to be more related to mastery of the technique each eye gives you, but then, that implies that only mastery is required, and having the eye or not becomes irrelevant after that. It is strange though.

Comment: the Susanoo Wiki entry "The third databook states that the user must first unlock Tsukuyomi and Amaterasu before they can gain Susanoo,[1] though this was only the case for Itachi. In the fourth databook, acquiring this technique is done through the user manifesting both Mangekyō Sharingan." Seems to support that idea. Manifesting both Mangekyou  is how you acquire the technique, but not a requirement for using it afterwards.

Comment: Actually, you need to activate Mangekyou in both the eyes to be able to use Susanoo, those techniques need not be Amaterasu and Tsukuyomi. Itachi's Mangekyou gave him those abilities, so he may have been referring only to himself. That was also why Kakashi could use Susanoo after Obito "gifted" him both the Sharingans (which is another strange development by itself). In Obito/Kakashi's case, the Mangekyou powers happened to be the long-range Kamui and short-range Kamui. Sasuke did activate Amaterasu and Tsukuyomi as his Mangekyou powers, and we don't know what Madara's Mangekyou powers were.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52384/discussion-between-masked-man-and-ryan).

Answer (score 4):

I've found some information on [this](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha) site why Madara got his eyes and his young body.

> Due to the manner of his revival and the experiments done by Kabuto, Madara retained access to abilities he obtained late in life (like his Wood Release and Rinnegan), while at the same time retaining the youthful body of his prime.

So he hasn't been revived "normally"

Since Nagato never lost his eyes he's revived with them too. So Madara actually did duplicate his eyes with the help of Kabuto. Since we don't know what would have happened if he would have been revived "normally" (at least not yet) we can't say whether it is that easy to duplicate the eyes or it was a coincidence that the eyes are now duplicated.

Long answer short: 
It is possible to duplicate the eyes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, let's say you reanimated Itachi. Sasuke, for arguments sake, doesn't have an eternal mangekyou, so he needs to switch eyes with someone. If he switched with Itachi, Sasuke would have good eyes, and Itachi, the worse ones.

I'm almost certain you can't reanimate a person twice at the same time, otherwise we'd have seen a lot more Kages in the fourth shinobi war. This means because you can only revive someone once at a time, and upon death/revival the reanimated body's eyes flake off and diminish, only four of a certain set of eyes can exist at a time because the eyes destroy themselves when the reanimation is destroyed.

This means, at a time, you can only have 4 eyes in existence (Two in the reanimation, and two in the reanimated persons original body in a coffin, if they haven't rotted away already) .

Comment: Yes, but let's say Person A has a rinnegan. Person A dies and his eyes are taken to person B. Person B dies and his eyes are taken to person C. Person C is still alive, and Persons A and B get reanimated. There are now 3 pairs of the same Rinnegan in existence. The real ones on Person C, and "fake" ones on A and B.

Comment: It kinda does. If Itachi hadn't have sealed Nagato, when Madara was reanimated, Nagato, Tobi *and* Madara would all have the same Rinnegan.

Comment: Also, I removed the spoiler block because the question itself states that answers will be spoilers to anime viewers.

Comment: That's fine, and I see where you're coming from now. Also, I guess it is possible, as the re animator can choose what aspects of the person they are reanimating to reanimate, e.g. a certain time of their life when they were most powerful, but with advanced jutsu they learned later in life.